# How to disable radio option button withou id and use angular rendering2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to disable the male radio button without use id. and using the angular rendering2. but not working.
without a change in html.only change in form.ts file

form.html

```
  <label>
    <input type="radio"  value="male" formControlName="gender">
      <span>male</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input  type="radio" value="female" formControlName="gender">
      <span>female</span>
  </label>
</form>
```

form.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit , Renderer2, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reg-form',
  templateUrl: './reg-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./reg-form.component.css']
})
export class RegFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  @ViewChild('gender', {static: false}) Input: ElementRef;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private renderer: Renderer2) {

    this.form = fb.group({
      gender: ['male', [Validators.required]]

    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {

this.renderer.setProperty(this.Input, 'disabled', 'true');

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont use disable using component variable like this

```
<input type="radio" name="disabled" [attr.disabled]="isDisabled" />
```

And in your component

```
export class RegFormComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  isDisabled: boolean;
  @ViewChild('gender', {static: false}) Input: ElementRef;
  constructor(fb: FormBuilder, private renderer: Renderer2) {

    this.form = fb.group({
      gender: ['male', [Validators.required]]

    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {

this.renderer.setProperty(this.Input, 'disabled', 'true');
    this.isDisabled = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Not use disable in form.html because form is dynamic generate.